# Copy data from en language version to other language version

Tags: powershell-extensions

I need to copy item field data from en language to all other available languagesin all versions. Any powershell script of achieving this.

Comment: https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items/item-languages

Comment: @MichaelWest these script create a new version doesn't copy value to existing version. I am looking for something that copy value to existing version

Comment: I just want to clarify that the Add-ItemLanguage command does copy existing values. You can configure if you do not want this with the -DoNotCopyFields flag. Additionally, you can specify which fields you do not want to have copied by using -IgnoredFields

Answer (score 0):

Probably the below script can help you. The comments are added to the script to make each step obvious. You can do modifications to it to suit your purpose -

```
#Get all language versions defined in System/Languages
$languages = Get-ChildItem /sitecore/System/Languages -recurse | Select $_.name | Where-Object {$_.name -ne "en"} | Select Name

#Ensuring correct items are updated by comparing the template ID 
$items = Get-ChildItem -Path "/sitecore/<your item location>" -Recurse | 
    Where-Object {'<item template id>' -contains $_.TemplateID}

#Bulk update context to improve performance
New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Data.BulkUpdateContext) {

    foreach($item in $items) {
        foreach($language in $languages) {
            $languageVersion = Get-Item -Path $item.Paths.Path -Language $language.Name

            #Check if language version already exists
            if($languageVersion -eq $null){
                Write-Host "Creating "$language.Name" version for "$item.Name
                Add-ItemLanguage -Item $item -Language "en" -TargetLanguage $language.Name -IfExist OverwriteLatest
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The script is also available at my [blog](https://ghanendras.blogspot.com/2020/08/sitecore-powershell-script-to-create.html).