# How to copy images included in content using Sitecore PowerShell Extension

Tags: powershell-extensions

I would like to know how to copy Sitecore Media Library content from Sitecore page one language to second language?

Comment: Do you want to create a version of a Sitecore item like Media Library? This article can help. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/26199/copy-data-from-en-language-version-to-other-language-version

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you, use this approach and enhance it as per your needs. However, it will give you at least a start to doing this.

What you need to do is to provide the path of your `Item` and the `Image Field` name. It will give you the `Media Item ID` and you can get that item and create a new language version of that. I have also mentioned some comments where you need to update the values.

```
# Here you need to provide your item ID and the language version of that item.
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:" -Uri "sitecore://master/<YOUR-ITEM-ID>?lang=en-us&ver=1"

# Here you need to provide your Image field name and you will get that image item
$imageField = [Sitecore.Data.Fields.ImageField]$item.Fields["YOUR-FIELD-NAME"]

# Here you need to get the item ID from the image field and get that image item using the ID
$newitem = Get-Item -Path master: -ID $imageField.mediaID

# Create a new Language item of the image field by providing the Target Language name 
Add-ItemLanguage -Item $newitem -Language "en-US" -TargetLanguage "en" -IfExist OverwriteLatest
```

If you want to make it recursive for all the items of a specific template type, then you can enhance this script.

Thanks